# Setbacks meaning

Tags: building-regulations

We are building/renovating our detached garage that is behind our house. I’m trying to understand the setback rules. I just excerpted what is relevant…

SIDEYARD (interior):
One-Story: Total of 10% of lot width; No setback shall be required to exceed five (5) feet nor be less than three (3) feet

SIDEYARD (exterior): 10 feet minimum

REAR YARD:
One-Story: 15 feet or average 15 feet with minimum of 10 feet

It’s really hard to get a hold of the Torrance building permit folks or the plan checkers.

Can someone explain the side yard (exterior and interior) setback rules? Also the rear yard rule?

Our lot is 40’ wide.  We have neighbors to the left and the right. Our rear property line is along an alley (the alley is wide enough for one car to drive through at a time)

So according to the rules…
Side yard setback (exterior)- total of 10%. Which means a total of 4’

Side yard setback (interior) - 10’ minimum

Rear yard: 15 feet or average 15 feet with minimum of 10 feet

If we want to build a structure what do these rules mean in regard to the structure and our property line?

I’m particularly confused with the interior and exterior meanings.

Comment: Is your lot on a corner?

Comment: It is not on a corner.

Comment: I suggest talking to an architect familiar with your local. I think the interior means lot with adjacent lots on both sides and the exterior mean the first or the last lot in the block. You shall also figure out the minimum space required between buildings.

Comment: The "nor be less than three (3) feet" would appear to apply to *each* side, so not "total of 4 feet" as I read that - total of 6 feet is your bare minimum "total" side setbacks added together. Language is a bit murky, IMHO. It would appear to allow an 80 foot lot to have 3 feet on one side and 5 feet on the other. For a 40 foot lot I read that as "two 3 foot minimums beat a 4 foot total."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You don't need to worry about "exterior side yards"

Since you aren't on a corner lot, you don't have an "exterior side yard", as that is a side yard that faces a street, just two "interior side yards."  As to that rear yard rule? The averaging is only needed if your rear lot line (boundary) isn't parallel to the front yard line, for a lot that say is trapezoidal in shape because it's on a curve, or is backed up to a creek or other meandering feature.  If you have a traditional rectangular "gridiron" lot, you just need the 15' minimum back yard.